# Android Webview avoid word wrap

Tags: android, webview, zooming, word-wrap

I want to display 600 lines of text, each with a length of 800 characters, in a webview. However, I don't want the text to be word wrapped, so that if the user wants to see the whole content, it has to scroll both vertically and horizontally. Is this possible in a webview?

I would also like to be able to zoom out until the whole content appears in the screen. Of course, in this case the only thing that would be seen is a black square because the text would be too small too read.

Answer (score -1):

String ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";
mWebview.getSettings().setUserAgentString(ua);

Comment: seems as though its loading your site in a mobile view

Comment: That doesn't do anything.